# How to modify the img tag's src and width value of a webpage using lazyload.js technology while scrolling

Tags: javascript

guys
thank you for coming in.I need your help:
i have a trouble when I want to change the web page's img tag's src and width when I'm reading it(scroll) by use chrome extension-Tampermonkey
I try to change these on window onload but  failed,because it use lazyload.js technology  to load(change) img tag, if I changed by window onload,Only the first picture in the viewable area of the webpage will be changed, and the rest of the pictures will not be visible！
if you can help me or give me some suggestions it's very cool! thanks a lot!

```html
original html img tag codes:
<img alt="xxxx" data-original="https://image.xxx.com/images/xxxxx.png?small" src="https://image.xxx.com/images/xxxxx.png?small" width="450" title="" style="display: block; outline: red dashed 1px;">

I want to changed like this(Remove ?small and change img tag's width when scroll):
<img alt="xxxx" data-original="https://image.xxx.com/images/xxxxx.png" src="https://image.xxx.com/images/xxxxx.png" width="450" title="" style="display: block; outline: red dashed 1px;width: 100%;"
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Lazy Loading Images**
>
> Use a blank.gif as the src of images, and include the width and height
>   of the final image.
>
> **HTML**
>
> **JavaScript**
>
> ```
> !function(window){
>   var $q = function(q, res){
>         if (document.querySelectorAll) {
>           res = document.querySelectorAll(q);
>         } else {
>           var d=document
>             , a=d.styleSheets[0] || d.createStyleSheet();
>           a.addRule(q,'f:b');
>           for(var l=d.all,b=0,c=[],f=l.length;b<f;b++)
>             l[b].currentStyle.f && c.push(l[b]);
>
>           a.removeRule(0);
>           res = c;
>         }
>         return res;
>       }
>     , addEventListener = function(evt, fn){
>         window.addEventListener
>           ? this.addEventListener(evt, fn, false)
>           : (window.attachEvent)
>             ? this.attachEvent('on' + evt, fn)
>             : this['on' + evt] = fn;
>       }
>     , _has = function(obj, key) {
>         return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key);
>       }
>     ;
>
>   function loadImage (el, fn) {
>     var img = new Image()
>       , src = el.getAttribute('data-src');
>     img.onload = function() {
>       if (!! el.parent)
>         el.parent.replaceChild(img, el)
>       else
>         el.src = src;
>
>       fn? fn() : null;
>     }
>     img.src = src;
>   }
>
>   function elementInViewport(el) {
>     var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect()
>
>     return (
>        rect.top    >= 0
>     && rect.left   >= 0
>     && rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
>     )
>   }
>
>     var images = new Array()
>       , query = $q('img.lazy')
>       , processScroll = function(){
>           for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
>             if (elementInViewport(images[i])) {
>               loadImage(images[i], function () {
>                 images.splice(i, i);
>               });
>             }
>           };
>         }
>       ;
>     // Array.prototype.slice.call is not callable under our lovely IE8 
>     for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
>       images.push(query[i]);
>     };
>
>     processScroll();
>     addEventListener('scroll',processScroll);
>
> }(this);​
> ```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/